# get started minutes from 0:00:00 type values

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm not really used to sql but I have a csv file with a lot of rows and columns so I decided to do the needed work in sql.
I have a Table with 3 columns and a few thousand rows.

Column `duration` is type varchar and includes duration of phoncalls in this format: `hours:minuts:seconds`.

I need to calculate $ per started minute. Let's say 100$ per minute. So if `duration` contains `0:13:25` it has to be 1400$.

my unsuccessful attempt was to add a new row "minutes", insert the number of started minutes and then go on calculating with it. But to me it doesn't matter how the solution works.

Since it's been a few years since I worked with sql I would be glad if someone can come up with a copy-paste solution I can use.

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results as *text tables* in the question.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Thanks for your quick replys. 
I wasn't really sure on how to give a usefull example since i have no usefull sql strings so far. 

@RiggsFolly that looks good but i get some strange outputs.
My first row is:

source | destination | duration 
4940xxxxxx | 00893xxxxx | 00:01:07

When i use your statement the result is 701.67. It should be 200 and I dont even understand how 701.67 is a possible output when starting with 1 minute 7 seconds.

Comment: Its always best to follow @GordonLinoff requests. If you show us something that resembles your actual data, we can come up with a better answer

Comment: I do, I made a WOOPS,  in the mathematics, it happens ! See answer

Comment: @RiggsFolly I'm glad your smarter than me :-D works perfect! Thanks for your help guys. Only 30 minutes for something that would take few hours for me! Stay safe
edit: how can I mark your answer as solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data looks like this then

```
source     | destination | duration 
4940xxxxxx | 00893xxxxx  | 00:01:07

select ROUND(((minute('00:01:07')*60 + second('00:01:07'))/60)*100, 2) as Extausionate_Bill;
```

Charging for every started minute

```
select CEILING(((minute('00:01:07')*60 + second('00:01:07'))/60))*100 as Extausionate_Bill;
```

Comment: oops I was a bit too quick. I have to charge every started minute. so 00:01:07 should be 200$, right now it calculates it per second so i get 111.67.

Comment: So you woudl like me to play with the mathematics?

Comment: I get what your statement does but unfortunately I don't know how to change it the way i need it. My best try would be do a +29 seconds before I do your statement.
But that doesn't seem too smart.

Comment: See if that fits better

Comment: Perfect! I also kinda get the CEILING command. Thanks a lot!